# Sort Map<String, Object[]>

Tags: java, treemap

I've created user defined Map i.e.

```
Map<String, Object[]> pass = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
```

Here I'm adding data to it inside for loop as shown below.

```
int row = 0;

 row++; 
 pass.put(row + "", new Object[] {"Data 1 : ","A"});
 row++;
 pass.put(row + "", new Object[] {"Data 2:", "B"});
 row++;
 pass.put(row + "", new Object[] {"Data 3:", "C"});
 row++;
 pass.put(row + "", new Object[] {"Data 4:", "D"});
```

But this data is not same as added order. Map is storing these data in random order. But I want these data in order. What needs to be done?

Comment: Why not use `Map<Integer, Object[]>`, or, well, `List<Object[]>`?

Comment: Its sorted by String, just as you have coded it to do. If you intended it to be sorted by number for example, I suggest you use an Integer instead.

Comment: Map is key-value 'storage' Your question does not make sense.

Comment: The data in a `TreeMap` is definitely not in random order. Your definition of _in order_ might not be the same as the `TreeMap`'s though.

Comment: Instead of using an `Object[]` why not use an actual class for your data?

Comment: Can you show what your `pass` map actually contains after insertion and tell us what order you actually expected?

Answer (score 7):

The `TreeMap` will sort your keys in their natural order (unless you inject a specific `Comparator` in its constructor).

In this case, it will use the lexicographical order for `String`s.

Lexicographical order implies that:

- `1` will come before `2`, **but**
- `10` will come before `2` **as well**!

If you need your keys to be sorted in numerical order, use `Integer` (or any `Number`) for a key.

If instead, you need to retain the **insertion** order and don't care about sorting keys, you can use a `LinkedHashMap`.

As [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2356554/keith) points out, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String)'s the Java documentation for lexicographic `String` comparison.

Comment: Just going to add: here's the latest [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) for lexicographical comparisons

Comment: @Mena: Thanks... Solved... Changed my Map here...
 Map<Integer, Object[]> pass = new TreeMap<Integer, Object[]>();